# Generate class diagram which includes relation based on Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea, diagram, class-diagram

I'm looking for the plugin to generate diagram class which includes relation between classes which was done in `Hibernate`.I have used `doxygen` but it doesn't generate the relation between classes. For example I have classes where there are multiple relation such as `OnToMany`, `ManyToOne`.

**Update**
I'm using `Intellij`

Comment: http://www.agilej.com/ is a good eclipse plugin

Answer (score 1):

If you happen to be using NetBeans as your IDE, then this plugin -> [jeddict](https://jeddict.github.io/) would definately do the trick for you as one of its features is reverse engineering based on JPA annotated classes. I have used it in the past for one of my projects and i was not dissapointed.

Comment: I'm using `Intellij IDE`

Answer (score 1):

I used `ObjectAid` plugin for `eclipse`: http://www.objectaid.com/installation